# Can't find GOPATH even set env path

Tags: go, path, environment

Using the root user installed go on linux.

Set go path in the ~/.zshrc file:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

```
$ ls $HOME/go
bin pkg src

$ ls $HOME/go/bin
asmfmt  dlv  errcheck  fillstruct  gocode  gocode-gomod  godef  gogetdoc  goimports  golint  gometalinter  gomodifytags  gorename  gotags  gounit  guru  iferr  impl  keyify  motion
```

But `go env` returned:

```
zsh: command not found: go
```

Why?

---

## Addition

```
$ whereis go
go: /usr/local/go
```

Set `/usr/local` to ~/.zshrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/
```

Source it. Run `go env` returned:

```
zsh: permission denied: go
```

Comment: Add the directory where you installed Go to your PATH.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Add something to the question.

Comment: give yourself a `export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:${PATH}`

Comment: @ScottStensland It works now! So `GOPATH` should be `/usr/local/go` which been installed?

Comment: @02040402 Do not set GOPATH to the installation directory.  A simple approach is to not set GOPATH at all. In this case the go tool will use $HOME/go as the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, your ~/.zshrc should set PATH to reference Go, as seen in the [Go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#zsh):

> Edit your `~/.zshrc` file to add the following line:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

> Save and exit your editor. Then, source your `~/.zshrc`.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

As explained in the [default `GOPATH`](https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/) and [issue 17262](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262), you don't need to set GOPATH.

But since [Go 1.11 and its modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), you can now makes entire projects *without* ever using the default `GOPATH` at all: everything would remain local to your project.

> As of Go 1.11, the `go` command enables the use of modules when the current directory or any parent directory has a `go.mod`, provided the directory is outside `$GOPATH/src`.
>   (Inside `$GOPATH/src`, for compatibility, the `go` command still runs in the old `GOPATH` mode, even if a `go.mod` is found)